# Why need even number of keyword parameters in Common Lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, keyword-argument

I am trying to implement tail call recursive factorial in Common Lisp, to try it and just experience it.

I copied some code and rewrote it in Common Lisp like so:

```
(defun tailrecsum (x &key (running-total 0 running-total-p))
    (if (= x 0)
        (if running-total-p running-total 0)
        (tailrecsum (- x 1) (+ running-total x))))
```

However, I get first a warning:

```
SIMPLE-WARNING: 
The function has an odd number of arguments in the keyword portion.
```

And when trying to run it, I get an error:

```
SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR: 
odd number of &KEY arguments
```

Why can't I have an odd number of keyword arguments? What's the problem with that and what can I do about it?

For example in Python I could write:

```
def func(a, b=10):
    print([a, b])
```

So I would have an odd number, one, of keyword arguments. No issues there.

Comment: You're missing the keyword in the call: `(tailrecsum (- x 1) (+ running-total x))` => `(tailrecsum (- x 1) :running-total (+ running-total x))`

Comment: @jkiiski Can you make that an answer? Then I can accept it. Somehow it still says `Control stack guard page temporarily disabled: proceed with caution CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED: #<SB-KERNEL::CONTROL-STACK-EXHAUSTED {1004EAA5D3}>
Out[46]:` though at anything higher than `(print (tailrecsum 19469))` =(

Comment: What implementation are you using? Do you have any optimization qualities set? It seems like the tail recursion is not being optimized. I don't have that problem on SBCL.

Comment: I am using SBCL 1.3.8. I read that some implementations don't have TCO, as it is not demanded by any Common LISP standard, but that SBCL should have it.

Comment: @jkiiski Aha, In SBCL directly, this does not cause the error, but in my notebook it does! (using cl-jupyter). Thanks for pointing it out, that in your SBCL it works as expected.

Comment: I imagine cl-jupyter must be setting the optimization qualities for debugging (such as `(DECLAIM (OPTIMIZE (DEBUG 3)))`), which disables TCO on SBCL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error doesn't refer to the number of keyword parameters; rather it means the number of arguments you call the function with. Since keywords arguments by definition need to be in pairs (`:KEYWORD VALUE`), having odd number of arguments means you must be missing something.

In this case you're missing the keyword in

```
(tailrecsum (- x 1) (+ running-total x))
```

which should be

```
(tailrecsum (- x 1) :running-total (+ running-total x))
```